# Is there a relationship between an inner type hierarchy and the component type projections?

Tags: scala, generics, types, scala-3, type-projection

In the example below, is it possible to write `updateShape` with the proper constraints so I don't need the three casts, the two in updateShape and the one at the call site?

```
trait ShapeModule:
  module =>
  type D

  trait Shape:
    def id: String
    override def toString =
      s"${module.getClass.getSimpleName()}>${getClass.getSimpleName}:$id"

  class ShapeStart(val id: String, val dims: D) extends Shape:
    def area: Double = module.area(dims)
    def next: ShapeFinished = ShapeFinished(id, dims)

  class ShapeFinished(id: String, dims: D) extends ShapeStart(id, dims):
    override def area: Double = super.area + 10.0
    def restart: ShapeStart = ShapeStart(id, dims)

  def area(dims: D): Double

type ShapeBase = ShapeModule#Shape

case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]):
  def updateShape[SS <: S, ST <: ShapeBase, T <: ShapeBase](
      id: String,
      f: SS => ST
  ): Paper[T] =
    val nextShapes =
      shapes.map(s => if s.id == id then f(s.asInstanceOf[SS]) else s)
    copy(shapes = nextShapes.asInstanceOf[Seq[T]])

object Circle extends ShapeModule:
  type D = Double
  def area(radius: Double) = Math.PI * radius * radius

object Rect extends ShapeModule:
  type D = (Double, Double)
  def area(dims: (Double, Double)) =
    val (w, h) = dims
    w * h

val circleStart = Circle.ShapeStart("C1", 2.0)
val rectStart = Rect.ShapeStart("R1", (2.0, 3.0))

val paperStart = Paper(Seq(circleStart, rectStart))
val paperFinish = paperStart.copy(
  paperStart.shapes.map(_.next)
)

val paperStart2 = paperFinish.updateShape("C1", _.restart)
paperStart2.asInstanceOf[Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeStart]].shapes.map(_.area)
```

All three type parameters in `updateShape` would ideally be more specific. It seems there are two type hierarchies in this example, one in the inner Shape > ShapeStart > ShapeFinished hierarchy, and one described with type projections across all modules (e.g. `ShapeModule#ShapeStart`). Is there any relationship between these two that can be used to describe updateShape? Are there good blogs/papers on the subject? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ShapeStart` has `def area` and `ShapeFinished` has `def area`, it makes sense to add `def area` to `Shape`, doesn't it?

In `if s.id == id then f(s) else s` there's not much sense to consider `f: S => S1` because then-branch returns `S1` while else-branch returns `S`, so totally if-then-else returns the parent type `ShapeBase` (or `S | S1`). So it's enough to have `f: S => ShapeBase`, anyway `.map` returns `Seq[ShapeBase]` (or `Seq[S | S1]`).

Otherwise if you want to return different subtypes from different branches then you need to know at compile time whether `s.id == id` i.e. to move `id` to type level. If you want to return different subtypes for different elements of the collection then `Seq` is not a proper data type, you need heterogeneous list (`Tuple`) and polymorphic function.

I tried to minimize the number of generics:

```
trait ShapeModule:
  module =>
  type D

  trait Shape:
    def id: String
    def area: Double
    override def toString =
      s"${module.getClass.getSimpleName}>${getClass.getSimpleName}:$id"

  class ShapeStart(val id: String, val dims: D) extends Shape:
    def area: Double = module.area(dims)
    def next: ShapeFinished = ShapeFinished(id, dims)

  class ShapeFinished(id: String, dims: D) extends ShapeStart(id, dims):
    override def area: Double = super.area + 10.0
    def restart: ShapeStart = ShapeStart(id, dims)

  def area(dims: D): Double

type ShapeBase = ShapeModule#Shape

case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]):
  def updateShape(id: String, f: S => ShapeBase): Paper[ShapeBase] =
    val nextShapes: Seq[ShapeBase] =
      shapes.map(s => if s.id == id then f(s) else s)
    copy(shapes = nextShapes)

object Circle extends ShapeModule:
  type D = Double
  def area(radius: Double) = Math.PI * radius * radius

object Rect extends ShapeModule:
  type D = (Double, Double)
  def area(dims: (Double, Double)) =
    val (w, h) = dims
    w * h

val circleStart = Circle.ShapeStart("C1", 2.0)
val rectStart = Rect.ShapeStart("R1", (2.0, 3.0))

val paperStart: Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeStart] = Paper(Seq(circleStart, rectStart))
val paperFinish: Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeFinished] = paperStart.copy(
  paperStart.shapes.map(_.next)
)

val paperStart2: Paper[ShapeBase] = paperFinish.updateShape("C1", _.restart)
paperStart2.shapes.map(_.area)
```

The reason to have more generics is additional type safety, but additional type safety is an illusion if you have to cast.

Or we can move the default implementation of `area` to `Shape` if we add `def dims` to `Shape` since both `ShapeStart` and `ShapeFinished` have `def dims`

```
trait Shape:
  def id: String
  def dims: D
  def area: Double = module.area(dims)

  override def toString =
    s"${module.getClass.getSimpleName}>${getClass.getSimpleName}:$id"

class ShapeStart(val id: String, val dims: D) extends Shape:
  def next: ShapeFinished = ShapeFinished(id, dims)

class ShapeFinished(id: String, dims: D) extends ShapeStart(id, dims):
  override def area: Double = super.area + 10.0
  def restart: ShapeStart = ShapeStart(id, dims)
```

---

If you can't add `area` to `Shape` because there can be other inheritors of `Shape` without `area` then here is an implementation with union types

```
trait ShapeModule:
  module =>
  type D

  trait Shape:
    def id: String
    override def toString =
      s"${module.getClass.getSimpleName}>${getClass.getSimpleName}:$id"

  class ShapeStart(val id: String, val dims: D) extends Shape:
    def area: Double = module.area(dims)
    def next: ShapeFinished = ShapeFinished(id, dims)

  class ShapeFinished(id: String, dims: D) extends ShapeStart(id, dims):
    override def area: Double = super.area + 10.0
    def restart: ShapeStart = ShapeStart(id, dims)

  def area(dims: D): Double

type ShapeBase = ShapeModule#Shape

case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]):
  def updateShape[S1 <: ShapeBase](id: String, f: S => S1): Paper[S | S1] =
    val nextShapes: Seq[S | S1] =
      shapes.map(s => if s.id == id then f(s) else s)
    copy(shapes = nextShapes)

object Circle extends ShapeModule:
  type D = Double
  def area(radius: Double) = Math.PI * radius * radius

object Rect extends ShapeModule:
  type D = (Double, Double)
  def area(dims: (Double, Double)) =
    val (w, h) = dims
    w * h

val circleStart = Circle.ShapeStart("C1", 2.0)
val rectStart = Rect.ShapeStart("R1", (2.0, 3.0))

val paperStart: Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeStart] = Paper(Seq(circleStart, rectStart))
val paperFinish: Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeFinished] = paperStart.copy(
  paperStart.shapes.map(_.next)
)

val paperStart2: Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeStart /*ShapeModule#ShapeStart | ShapeModule#ShapeFinished*/] =
  paperFinish.updateShape("C1", _.restart)
paperStart2.shapes.map(_.area)
```

Since `ShapeFinished` extends `ShapeStart`, `ShapeModule#ShapeStart | ShapeModule#ShapeFinished` is just `ShapeModule#ShapeStart`.

---

Since you apply `updateShape` to `_.restart : ShapeFinished => ShapeStart` i.e. `S=ShapeFinished`, `S1=ShapeStart`, `ShapeFinished <: ShapeStart`, we can add bound `S1 >: S`, then  `S | S1 = S1`

```
case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]):
  def updateShape[S1 >: S <: ShapeBase](id: String, f: S => S1): Paper[S1] =
    val nextShapes: Seq[S1] =
      shapes.map(s => if s.id == id then f(s) else s)
    copy(shapes = nextShapes)
```

Maybe that's what you were looking for.

Most general signature is

```
case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]):
  def updateShape[SS >: S /*<: ShapeBase*/,
                  ST /*<: ShapeBase*/,
                  T >: (SS | ST) <: ShapeBase
                 ](
    id: String,
    f: SS => ST
  ): Paper[T] =
    val nextShapes: Seq[T] =
      shapes.map(s => if s.id == id then f(s) else s)
    copy(shapes = nextShapes)
```

But then you'll have to specify the type of lambda: `(_: ShapeModule#ShapeFinished).restart` instead of just `_.restart`.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have included the example that I have another subclass of `Shape` that doesn't respond to `area`, so it cannot simply be moved.  I also attempted to write `updateShape` using TypeTest, keeping both `id` and using the type, but I removed this to simplify the example. You're right that I have too many type parameters for the given example, but I put them in to illustrate the flexibility I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks again.

Comment: @MattJacobus The main point is that if-then-else returns the parent type.

Comment: But this can be written `val paperStart3: Paper[ShapeModule#ShapeStart] = paperFinish.copy(
  shapes = paperFinish.shapes.updated(0, paperFinish.shapes(0).restart)
)
`

Comment: @MattJacobus See the update with union types for the case when `area` can't be added to `Shape`

Comment: @MattJacobus See update `case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]): { def updateShape[S1 >: S <: ShapeBase](id: String, f: S => S1): Paper[S1] = { val nextShapes: Seq[S1] = ...`

Comment: Thanks!  I should have seen the union solution.  I think that works.  For future reference, is there any relationship between the type projections and the inner type hierarchy that I can use for other methods?

Comment: @MattJacobus Most general signature is `case class Paper[S <: ShapeBase](shapes: Seq[S]) { def updateShape[SS >: S /*<: ShapeBase*/, ST /*<: ShapeBase*/, T >: SS | ST <: ShapeBase](id: String, f: SS => ST): Paper[T] = { val nextShapes: Seq[T] = ...`. But then you'll have to specify the type of lambda: `(_: ShapeModule#ShapeFinished).restart` instead of just `_.restart`

Comment: @MattJacobus Not sure I understand what relationship you're asking about

Comment: @MattJacobus If `A <: B` and inner types `C <: D` (i.e. `x.C <: x.D`) then `A#C <: A#D <: B#D`, `A#C <: B#C <: B#D`. Are you asking about such relationship? https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance